# Amazon cloudsearch not working

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I have the following code for implementing cloudsearch domain using javascript SDK.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="aws-sdk-2.172.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     console.log(AWS);
     AWS.config.apiVersions = {
      cloudsearch: 'latest',
    };
    var csd = new AWS.CloudSearchDomain({endpoint: 'search-mydomain-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com',region:'us-west-2'});
    var params = {query:'test'};
    csd.search(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
      else     console.log(data); 
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

But it shows an error in the console

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 400.

What i need to change in the code and aws account?

Answer (score 2):

CloudSearch does not support cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) requests, so you cannot do an async request directly to the CloudSearch domain.  What I ended up doing when I came across this issue was create an API Gateway to handle the request, and added CORS support to that.  So the API Gateway accepts the request, sets up the necessary headers to enable CORS, and then relays the request to your CloudSearch domain.

Here are a couple of links that might be helpful in setting this up:

- [Using AWS API Gateway to Enable CORS for CloudSearch](http://aaronkenny.com/blog/using-aws-api-gateway-to-enable-cors-for-cloud-search/index.htm)
- [Enable CORS for an API Gateway Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)